# How to group records and retrieve only first group with top N records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have the following record set

```
ID          BatchID     ClientName           CreatedDateTime
----------- -------------- --------------- -----------------------
1           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:07:46.320
2           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:07:46.320
3           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:07:46.597
4           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:07:46.597
5           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:10:10.260
6           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:10:10.260
7           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:21:34.303
8           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:21:34.303
9           NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:21:44.780
10          NULL           B             2018-02-16 19:21:44.780
11          NULL           A             2018-02-16 19:24:35.623
12          NULL           A             2018-02-16 19:24:35.623
13          NULL           A             2018-02-16 19:24:42.867
14          NULL           A             2018-02-16 19:24:42.867
```

I am using LINQ to SQL in EF Core.

I want to filter the records where `BatchID` is `NULL` and then order the filtered records by `CreatedDateTime` and then group them by `ClientName` and then take top 5 records **from the first** Group.

Based on the given record set above it should return records with Ids 1,2,3,4,5 for ClientName `B`

So here is my query

```
 var result = await _DBContext.BatchRequests
                .Where(x => x.BatchID.HasValue == false)
                .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDateTime)
                .GroupBy(x => x.ClientName)
                .FirstAsync();
```

**ISSUE**
  1> The query returns Client `A`
  2> How do i Take only top 5 records

**Update 1**

Sql Profiler show the following, it doesnt even group in SQL

```
SELECT [x].[ID], [x].[BatchID], [x].[ClientName], [x].[CreatedDateTime]
FROM [BatchRequests] AS [x]
WHERE CASE
    WHEN [x].[BatchID] IS NULL
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END <> 0
ORDER BY [x].[ClientName]
```

Comment: Your `OrderBy` isn't going to have much meaning after the `GroupBy` - you have to order the groups. So how do you want to order the groups? (Also, a simple `x.BatchID == null` may product better SQL.)

Comment: FYI, EF Core has nothing in common with LINQ to SQL or EF6. For instance, as you already noticed it currently does not translate `GroupBy` queries to SQL.

Comment: well the grouping has to be done in SQL. Whats the use of retrieving all the records in memory and do grouping in memory and just take top N.

Comment: You will have to wait for EF Core 2.1. That's one reason I don't think EF Core is ready for production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, usually `OrderBy` has no effect (is ignored) if followed by `GroupBy` in `Queryable` implementations which translate LINQ queries to SQL.

Second, EF Core currently does not translate `GroupBy` queries to SQL, but processes them in memory (so called [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval)), which makes them highly inefficient. With that taken into account, you'd better split the work on two queries - one to take the `ClientName` of the first group, and second to take the desired result:

```
var baseQuery = _DBContext.BatchRequests
    .Where(x => x.BatchId == null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDateTime);

var clientName = await baseQuery
    .Select(x => x.ClientName)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var result = await baseQuery
    .Where(x => x.ClientName == clientName)
    .Take(5)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Actualy you can combine the two queries, but I'm not sure whether it will be more efficient (could be worse):

```
var baseQuery = _DBContext.BatchRequests
    .Where(x => x.BatchId == null)
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDateTime);

var result = await baseQuery
    .Where(x => x.ClientName == baseQuery.Select(y => y.ClientName).FirstOrDefault())
    .Take(5)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to project the group result like something this:

```
result = await _DBContext.BatchRequests
            .Where(x => x.BatchID.HasValue == false)
            .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDateTime)
            .ThenBy(x => x.ClientName)
            .GroupBy(x => x.ClientName)
            .Select( x => new { ClientName= x.ClientName,
                                 TopFive = x.Take(5)
                         })
            .FirstAsync();
```

Comment: did not work. It produces the same result and returns client `B`. In-fact the SQL profiler shows the exact same SQL as my query as i posted in Update 1 above

Comment: Are you sure this is the SQL getting generated?

Comment: yes, as someone pointed out there is no effect of order by when you have group by